# Get N rows of a group / thread / topic

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm looking for a right mysql query for my website http://watiseropderadio.nl (in dutch). It's a website to find out what songs have been played on the popular radio's in Holland.

I want to make a query what returns 13 rows for each radiostation. There are 8 different radiostation.

This is my table:

```
id       | radioname       | time  | artist    | song
--------------------------------------------------------------
23421    | radio 538       | 19:34 | Queen     | Bohemian
23422    | radio veronica  | 19:35 | Rammstein | Blablabla
23423    | slam fm         | 19:34 | Roxette   | Blablabla
23424    | 3fm             | 19:34 | Blabla    | Blablabla
....
```

It's a table with 3,000,000+ records and with these key's:

```
PRIMARY             PRIMARY  3083007   id
radioname           INDEX    8         radioname
track with artist   INDEX    23715     artist
                                       song
```

This what I want to be the output:

```
id       | radioname       | time  | artist    | song
--------------------------------------------------------------
23455    | radio 538       | 19:30 | Blabla    | Blablabla
23470    | radio 538       | 19:33 | Blabla    | Blablabla
23484    | radio 538       | 19:36 | Blabla    | Blablabla
23498    | radio 538       | 19:38 | Blabla    | Blablabla
total 13 x ....
23456    | radio veronica  | 19:29 | Blabla    | Blablabla
23476    | radio veronica  | 19:32 | Blabla    | Blablabla
23483    | radio veronica  | 19:36 | Blabla    | Blablabla
23495    | radio veronica  | 19:39 | Blabla    | Blablabla
total 13 x ....
```

The order of the result doesn't matter and the query has to be fast. I like to try it myself, but this is a little to much for me.

I don't know if the key's are goed for this job, can someone gives some advise?

Comment: Apart from your question: I'd use a numerical id for the radio station instead of each time saving the full name.

Comment: @abaumg I'm going to do that, thanks. Will it save a lot of time? Because the time for loading the records of last 2 hours is 3 (!) seconds.

Comment: I'm no MySQL guru and don't know *how much* time it will save, but it will save some time. And it's good database design.

Comment: It will save some time, but don't expect anything huge. The more important reason is to avoid spelling issues: If one users enters a station as "slam fm" and somebody else enter it as "Slam FM" or just "Slam" or some other variation, they'll look like different stations. With a separate station table, you can force them to be consistent.

Comment: Also, without a separate table, what if, say, you only keep one weeks' worth of data, and then a station goes off the air for a week? You lose all record of the existence of that station. This is called the "deletion anomoly" and is an issue in normalization. Can I plug my book? "A Sane Approach to Database Design", discusses this. I'm sure plenty of other good sources do also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky because, while there are ways to say "get me only 13 records for this query", to the best of my knowledge there's no way to directly say "get me only 13 records for this each value of field x".

The only way I can think of to do it is to add an "play number" field to the record, or to create another table to hold this number if you can't or don't want to change the "song played" record. Then when records are added to the table, give each the next available number for that radio station. (Actually MySQL has a feature to do this automatically.) Then your query could look for this index <=13, or if records can be deleted, have an inner query that does a "select station, max(play) as maxplay group by station", then the outer query could select "where play>maxplay-13"

**Update**

To set up the MySQL auto-increment, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html. Note particularly the discussion around the sentence, "For MyISAM and BDB tables you can specify AUTO_INCREMENT on a secondary column in a multiple-column index. In this case, the generated value for the AUTO_INCREMENT column is calculated as MAX(auto_increment_column) + 1 WHERE prefix=given-prefix. This is useful when you want to put data into ordered groups." (Frankly, it's been a while since I used this so I can't supply a lot of detail.)

Comment: That sounds clear. Can you link of explain this function 'Actually MySQL has a feature to do this automatically'?

Comment: Or just by `UPDATE table SET lastplay = lastplay - 1 WHERE radioname = 'radio 538' AND lastplay > 0`?

Comment: @harianus: See update. If I was using a database other than MySQL that doesn't have such an "autonumber within a prefix" feature, I think I would probably write code to assign sequence numbers, or assign them at the time you insert each record. "insert into playlist (... whatever ..., playnumber) values (... whatever ..., (select coalesce(max(playnumber),0)+1 from playlist where radioname=<new radioname>))"

Answer (score 0):

Is it acceptable to loop through the list of radio stations (as there are only 8) and fire off 8 separate queries? Something like

```
<?php
$stations = array('radio 538', 'radio veronica', 'slam fm', '3fm');
foreach ($stations as $station)
{
    $query = sprintf('SELECT * FROM table WHERE radioname="%s" ORDER BY time ASC LIMIT 0,13', $station);
    // do something
}
?>
```

[untested!]

Comment: It's acceptable, but I hoped for a mysql solution. But now I know there isn't, this will do the trick.